# Should I ask a new question or edit the current one?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have asked a question with bounty 4 months ago. Now, I am working on the same problem, but with an extra restriction (or requirement).
This extra restriction changes the nature of the problem and a completely different approach may be needed.

Now, should I ask a new question or edit the current one and add another bounty?

Answer (score 5):

> This extra restriction changes the nature of the problem and a completely different approach may be needed.

If the questions call for different answers, they're different questions.

It may turn out that the same approach is optimal in both cases, but even then, that would presumably require a different proof. And one of the questions may well have approaches that are not optimal in some sense but have other advantages (e.g. slower but easier to implement).

Please ask a new question.